# Unexpected errors in Visual Studio include files

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I've converted some legacy Fortran code to C using the f2c converter ([f2c](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/)), and I've created a Visual Studio 10 solution using Cmake on Windows 7 (64-bit).  I've also had to link my C++ program (test.cpp, containing my main function) with the f2c library (built on my system using nmake).  Although I've worked extensively with CMake and Visual Studio, after compiling the program I'm now receiving a number of cryptic errors related to the header files shipped with Visual Studio:

```
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\intrin.h(141): error C2059: syntax error : '('
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\intrin.h(141): error C2059: syntax error : '-'
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\intrin.h(141): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xcomplex(250): error C2027: use of undefined type '_Ty'
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xcomplex(250): error C2226: syntax error : unexpected type 'std::complex<_Other>'
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xcomplex(250): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xcomplex(250): error C2059: syntax error : '-'
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xcomplex(250): error C2065: '_Ty' : undeclared identifier
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xcomplex(250): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xcomplex(263): error C2065: '_Ty' : undeclared identifier
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xcomplex(263): error C2065: '_Ty' : undeclared identifier
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xcomplex(264): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xcomplex(264): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Creating a Visual Studio solution file from scratch doesn't seem to work very well either, and I am still receiving the same errors.  What can I do to track down the issue with these errors?  Obviously something is wrong with the files that I've included or written, but what could it be?  The errors don't immediately point to a certain section of the code, so debugging is challenging.

Here is a link to the f2c.h header file ([f2c.h](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/f2c.h)).  I've added

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

to the top and

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
 }
#endi
```

to the bottom of this header file, since my test.cpp is a C++ program.

Comment: This typically indicates one of two things: either some header has a dependency on another header and you didn't include that one, or there's a syntax error before the inclusion of the header (possibly in another header) that causes things in the header to be parsed incorrectly.

Comment: @Sven: Thanks, I've tried shuffling the order of the header files around, and it appears that moving `#include f2c.h` to the top of the file (with no headers before it) still produces the same errors, as well as some additional errors found in `math.h`.  I don't know how to fix things if `f2c.h` is indeed required, and the system header files can't be removed in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem is that `f2c.h` defines a number of macros, including some for math functions such as `abs`. These macros cause problems when those same identifiers are encountered in the standard headers.

For this reason, I recommend that you always include `f2c.h` as the last header in the file (or `#undef` the conflicting macros before including other files).

Comment: Thank you; this works really well.  Rather than `#undef` the macros, I moved the `f2c.h` so that it was the last header in the file.  This works perfectly!